# Alignment issue in Stack Exchange Data Explorer (SEDE) main page

Tags: bug, design, data-explorer

In the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer main page](https://data.stackexchange.com/), the list of Stack Exchange sites and its meta site details are displaying.

For the **Software Recommendations Meta Stack Exchange** site the details are displaying in the next line.

Screenshot for reference:

[image: Data Stack Exchange - Alignment issue]