# Few site and meta site names are ending with Stack Exchange and not all the sites in the data explorer main page

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer

In the [Stack Exchange Data Explorer main page](https://data.stackexchange.com/) the Stack Exchange site and it's meta site names are displaying.

For the following site and it's meta site's names are ending with Stack Exchange but not the all others.

- Software Recommendations Stack Exchange
- Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange
- Earth Science Stack Exchange
- Arduino Stack Exchange
- Joomla Stack Exchange
- Expatriates Stack Exchange
- Beer Stack Exchange

Why these site's names are only ending with Stack Exchange? Initially I thought these sites are recently created by Area 51 proposal. But checking in Area 51, these sites are proposed and launched in different time period.

Is it a bug?

---

<sub>Note: I have Noticed this issue when cross checking this [bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/291974/alignment-issue-in-stack-exchange-data-explorer-main-page)</sub>

Comment: This is a bug, as Tim Stone says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226483/long-sites-break-the-layout-on-the-front-page#comment741283_226483), it should be stripped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was in fact a bug, that [I just fixed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/332181/164200). The "Stack Exchange" should be removed from the site name, and it gets removed on new sites - we just never removed it from existing ones. I just manually updated them and the problem should be gone. (Copying my answer from the linked post)

> This has been fixed. We do replace the "Stack Exchange" when we import new Sites every week, but we don't update existing sites which is why these have lingered for a long time.
>
> I went ahead and manually corrected the Sites that had the "Stack Exchange" in the name still.